# Can JOOQ alias a Liquibase JSONB data type for H2/Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, h2, liquibase, jooq, jooq-codegen-maven

I'm using this H2 feature to create an alias for JSONB in the jdbc string:

```
spring.datasource.url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;INIT=create domain if not exists jsonb as text;MODE=PostgreSQL
```

But JOOQs' codegen liquibase support (generator pointed at liquibase files) doesn't recognize the JSONB column type.
and I keep getting:

> Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Unknown data type: "JSONB";

Is there a way to tell the generator to alias this data type to TEXT?

Comment: Can you post a bit more of what you're doing? Specifically, your liquibase migration is necessary here...

Answer (score 0):

You can try to init your h2 with `CREATE TYPE "JSONB" AS json`